# Does the Picasa API support querying and updating the list of users that an album is shared with?

Tags: api, acl, gdata, picasa

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the Picasa API to grant other users the ability to view private albums.  The developer's guide shows the following in the example data returned for the feed of a user's albums:

```
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList'
        type='application/atom+xml'
        href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/liz/albumid/albumID/acl?authkey=authKey&amp;v=2' />
```

However, when I request one of the access control list URLs for one of my own albums, it only returns exactly the same data as the URL for the album itself.  I couldn't find anything in the Picasa API documentation about it, but that looks similar to the functionality in the Google Docs API for sharing documents.  Does anyone know if it's supported for Picasa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I tried just about everything before I decided that all the unanswered questions out there about how to do it was a good indication that it still isn't doable (at least not using the API).

I found this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=292&q=share&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary), it doesn't seem to be very prioritized.